# Changing Activity on a clickable layout

Tags: android, android-widget

I have this clickable `LinearLayout` view, im trying to have it change `Activity` when clicked by every time i click the object i get a error.

```
final LinearLayout lindet = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.detials);
lindet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(SellingActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: Be more specific! What error?

Comment: can you pls paste error fro ur logcat

Comment: its closes the app when i click on the object, so there is no error in the IDE.. ikn the activity all i have is just setcontent view and theres no errors in the details activity

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to add the `DetailsActivity` to the `AndroidManifest`?

Answer (score 0):

Supporting Macarse I would add that use `SellingActivity.this.finish()` instead of `finish()`

I believe this will prove to be your problem solver.